# How to add spaces in a string using loops (Homework)

Tags: java, string, output, addition

So I'm working on a homework assignment using Strings and loops. Our professor would like us to add spaces in front of a word. The number of spaces should be the number input. So for example if you input 3 then it should output:

```
Java
 Java
  Java
   Java
```

I have seen some other questions like this but I would like to do it specifically using loops/a counter. So far I have

```
public static String printJavaPattern1(int numOfSpacesAtTheFront){
     String s2 = "";
     int  = 0;
     String ind = " ";
     if(count = 0){
         return s2;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Where is your loop? What **precisely** ***is*** your question? Also, why print Java four times when you input 3?

Comment: You did not make it clear to others ...

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm